# Vertical align links next to an image object

Tags: html, css

Having a little trouble here.

*I am trying to get the text to be in the middle of the image. I tried to vertically align but it did not work ?*

**For example:**

[image]

```css
li {
  display: inline;
  width: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object>
    <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**JSFiddle:**

*https://jsfiddle.net/n40qdv8n/*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the supplied markup is  invalid. You cannot have a `<object>` within a `<ul>`. You need to supply valid HTML before we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the vertical align on the image not the text https://jsfiddle.net/qb1xjt3u/

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="row">
        <ul class="menu">
          <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object>
          <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
li{
   display: inline;
   width: 30px;
   }
a {
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  text-align: center;

}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

object { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things to fix:

- The markup is invalid `<object>` can't be directly under `<ul>`, please wrap it into a `<li>` tag.
- You should use `display: inline-block` rather than `inline`, so the `width` could work, and I suggest to use `min-width` in this case.

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  outline: 1px solid aqua;
}

a {
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to skin a cat, but you could use flexbox on the parent UL and use the "align-items: center;" to get the effect you are looking for.

https://jsfiddle.net/radiantstatic/3ajjsdLc/

```css
ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
li{
   display: inline;
   width: 30px;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
a {
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  text-align: center;
  
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="row">
        <ul class="menu">
          <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object>
          <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

See more about flexbox here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes

Answer (score 0):

Make both `li` and your `object` have `display: inline-block;` and vertical-align: middle;:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
object {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <ul class="menu">
    <object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object>
    <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is wrong. We need to put li inside of direct ul but you use object so i have changed little bit

```css
li{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
   object {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
a {
  color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><object type="image/svg+xml" data="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2184/large/tortoise-and-turtle-shells-and-potential-problems-5437997a9781f.jpg" width="100px" height="75px"></object></li>
          <li><a href="#">but1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">but4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```